# Solving probability questions using tree diagram method

Tags: probability

How to find probability of one six when a six-sided die is thrown three times ? I tried out the tree diagram but I couldn't get the answer. Please if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: As a hint: since you don't care about the exact value of the non-$6$ outcomes of a single die roll, you can just imagine that there are only two possible outcomes, namely $6$ and $X$ where $X$ just stands for "not $6$".  Of course they have different probabilities, namely $\frac 16$ and $ \frac 56$.

Comment: When you say one six, I assume you mean exactly one six.  This is a binomial distribution with $p = \frac{1}{6}$ and $q = 1 - p = \frac{5}{6}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt at a tree. Note, there are $3$ ways to get a single $6$.

[image]